# KeyError5 while working with pandas to transform data from files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i need to read data from a csv and add two or more rows if the sum is less than or equal to five and save it to a new csv file.

**Expected output pattern:**

```
 Application  time_taken
  Serv6, Serv2         2.2
         Serv1         2.3
         Serv9         3.3
         Serv4         4.4
         Serv8         4.6
        Serv10         5.0
         Serv7         5.5
         Serv3         6.0
         Serv5         8.0
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-24-fc02128770c1>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/prasad.namala/Documents/Python Scripts/Programs/New_Csv.py', wdir='C:/Users/prasad.namala/Documents/Python Scripts/Programs')

  File "C:\Users\prasad.namala\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\prasad.namala\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/prasad.namala/Documents/Python Scripts/Programs/New_Csv.py", line 36, in <module>
    final_csv = value_checker(input_data)

  File "C:/Users/prasad.namala/Documents/Python Scripts/Programs/New_Csv.py", line 32, in value_checker
    return value_checker(new_df)

  File "C:/Users/prasad.namala/Documents/Python Scripts/Programs/New_Csv.py", line 20, in value_checker
    print(f"{df.loc[i,['Application']].item()}, {df.loc[i+1,['Application']].item()}")

  File "C:\Users\prasad.namala\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1494, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)

  File "C:\Users\prasad.namala\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 868, in _getitem_tuple
    return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)

  File "C:\Users\prasad.namala\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 988, in _getitem_lowerdim
    section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)

  File "C:\Users\prasad.namala\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1913, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)

  File "C:\Users\prasad.namala\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 141, in _get_label
    return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)

  File "C:\Users\prasad.namala\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3585, in xs
    loc = self.index.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\Users\prasad.namala\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 987, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 993, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

KeyError: 5
```

```
**Data in input csv file:**

Application  time_taken
       Serv6         1.0
       Serv2         1.2
       Serv1         2.3
       Serv9         3.3
       Serv4         4.4
       Serv8         4.6
      Serv10         5.0
       Serv7         5.5
       Serv3         6.0
       Serv5         8.0

**Here is the code:**

import pandas as pd

def value_checker(sf):
    col = []
    col1 = []
    sf.sort_values(by='time_taken', inplace= True)
    sf.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
    df = sf[sf['time_taken']<5]
    print(sf)
    if df.shape[0]>2:
        for i in range(0, df.shape[0], 2):
            if df.loc[i:i+1,['time_taken']].sum().item() <= 5:
                print(f"{df.loc[i,['Application']].item()}, {df.loc[i+1,['Application']].item()}")
                col.append(f"{df.loc[i,['Application']].item()}, {df.loc[i+1,['Application']].item()}")
#                print(df.loc[i,['time_taken']].item() + df.loc[i+1,['time_taken']].item())
                col1.append(df.loc[i,['time_taken']].item() + df.loc[i+1,['time_taken']].item())
                print(col1)
            else:
                print(f"in else block {i}th iter ")
                col.extend([df.loc[i,['Application']].item(), df.loc[i+1,['Application']].item()])
                col1.extend([df.loc[i,['time_taken']].item(), df.loc[i+1,['time_taken']].item()])
        new_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Application':col, 'time_taken': col1})
        new_df = pd.concat([new_df, sf[sf['time_taken']>=5]])
        if new_df[new_df['time_taken']<5].shape[0]>=2:
            return value_checker(new_df)
    return sf

input_data = pd.read_csv('inputfile.csv')
final_csv = value_checker(input_data)
final_csv.to_csv("Outputfile.csv",index=False)
print("Task Completed")
```

note: ignore print statements

The expected output should be in pattern as mentioned above. if the sum of any two rows is less then or equal to 5 add those again and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Will the new rows be added on the bottom of your dataframe? or be inserted in between the 2 values that satisfied your condition?

And what shall be the value of the ith row in the first column if the condition be met?

While waiting for your reply, to start, I think you'll have to do binary search in lists.

Editing my answer now :)). Try this:

```
# Placing your 2nd column's values in a list.

time_taken_vals = df.iloc[:,1].values.tolist() 

# Doing the search for each entry and creating a new list of values for the result to be used as your 3rd column's values.

sum_result = []
for i in range(0, len(time_taken_vals)):
    if time_taken_vals[i] + time_taken_vals[i+1] <= 5 and i != len(time_list)-1:
        sum_result.append(time_taken_vals[i] + time_taken_vals[i+1])
    else:
        sum_result.append('')
sum_result.append('') # to equate the length of the two lists

# Now all you need to do is use the sum_result as value of your new column

df['Sum of time taken'] = sum_result
```

So from your initial DataFrame:

```
Application  time_taken
   Serv6         1.0
   Serv2         1.2
   Serv1         2.3
   Serv9         3.3
   Serv4         4.4
   Serv8         4.6
  Serv10         5.0
   Serv7         5.5
   Serv3         6.0
   Serv5         8.0
```

The result would be:

```
Application  time_taken  Sum of time taken
   Serv6         1.0           2.2
   Serv2         1.2           3.5
   Serv1         2.3           
   Serv9         3.3           
   Serv4         4.4           
   Serv8         4.6           
  Serv10         5.0           
   Serv7         5.5           
   Serv3         6.0           
   Serv5         8.0
```

Because only `1.0` + `1.2` and `1.2` + `2.3` satisfies your condition.

Is this solution you're looking for? In any case, I hope this gives you an idea to solve your problem, good luck, and don't forget to upvote my answer, thank you :))

Comment: The added values are inserted in the placed of the rows that satisfies my condition. For which, i'm saving those into a new dataframe. In my code, the error occured in 1st recursive call of the function at 2nd iteration of for loop.

Comment: You don't need two iterations. Just two lists. Place first column in one, and the second column in another. Loop through the second one,creating a new list along the way using the condition you mentioned. I'll add the codes in a while, I'm using my phone right now and the format for answering is different lol.

Comment: Sure! I'll be waiting for your response. Meanwhile give a try. And do you know anything about the error(root cause) ?

Comment: Hi have you tried the code I presented in my edited answer? Anyway, for the root cause, what are you trying to achieve? To avoid this, I use `try:` and `except:` documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: Hey Joe, i started it again from scratch and got the expected output this time. Thanks for the support. Here is the output '''  Application  time_taken
0  Serv6, Serv2, Serv1         4.5
1         Serv4, Serv7         4.9
2                Serv9         3.3
3                Serv8         4.6
4               Serv10         5.0
5                Serv3         6.0
6                Serv5         8.0'''

Comment: Yeah sure, glad to help, an upvote would be nice if it's not so much trouble. Thanks, have a great one! :D

Comment: ```   Application                 time_taken
0  Serv6, Serv2, Serv1         4.5
1         Serv4, Serv7         4.9
2                Serv9         3.3
3                Serv8         4.6
4               Serv10         5.0
5                Serv3         6.0
6                Serv5         8.0```